What is "virtualization-based security"?
Microsoft's explanation of "virtualization-based security" is inadequate. They don't explain how it functions or what it cam do beyond memory segregation. What exactly does it consist of? Does it run programs with restricted filesystem access? Is it like gVisor?

Do the several pages at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs provide more information? They don't exactly talk about the implementation details, but they do mention several specific features that are grouped under the umbrella term, and those are explained elsewhere (e.g. Credential Guard being "LSASS in a VM").

@grawity They are vague. It mentions that "kernel mode code integrity" (KMCI) authenticates kernel drives, but didn't Windows already do that without VBS? A bullet point on this page mentions that "memory integrity" lets KMCI signature check kernel processes. Since when do kernels have processes? They are a single process.
